# When installing the application using Nullsoft, how to display the path in the Destination Folder based on the 32/64 bit windows OS

Tags: nsis

When installing the application using NULLSOFT, I wanted to show the path in the Destination folder based on the 32/64 bit windows operating system.

If it is 32 bit, it should be

```
C:\Program Files\
```

If it is 64 bit, it should be

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\
```

I used  `InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\ "` in the script. With that it is showing `C:\Program Files\` for both 32/64 bit OS.

If anyone has any idea, please help me out.

Comment: Are you installing a 32 bit program, or a 64 bit program?

Comment: It is a 32 bit program. That can install in either 32 bit or 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special, NSIS takes care of it for you.

```
InstallDir $ProgramFiles32\MyApp
Page Directory
Page InstFiles
```

will use `X:\Program Files\` on 32-bit Windows and `X:\Program Files (x86)\` on 64-bit Windows.

`$ProgramFiles` is an alias for `$ProgramFiles32` when you generate a 32-bit installer and an alias for `$ProgramFiles64` when you generate a 64-bit installer.

`$ProgramFiles64` should only be used if you are installing a 64-bit application!